# Can't receive ipn signal from PayPal

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, paypal

I am try to receive ipn signal from PayPal after transaction, but for someone reason i can't get it. This is my form (I send to paypal using simple form html):

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="checkout_form_id">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="mygmail@gmail.com" id="id_business"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="" id="id_amount"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Payment for victorywow.com" id="id_item_name"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="{{ paypal_url }}/paypal/" id="id_notify_url"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value={{ paypal_url }}?cancel_return= id="id_cancel_return"/>
    <input id="id_return_url" name="return" type="hidden" value="{{ paypal_url }}?success_return="/>
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="" id="id_invoice"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" id="id_cmd"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" id="id_charset"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" id="id_currency_code"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" id="id_no_shipping" />
    <input type="button" class="form_button pay_pal_but" value="PAY NOW">
</form>
```

Some variable such `invoice_id`,`amount` and so on I add by `js`.
'paypal_url' I create in `views.py` : `request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('index'))` (`index` is url like this`'^$'`)
`urls.py`:

```
url(r'^paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls'))
```

`signals.py`:

```
from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received
from .models import Order

def ipn_geter(sender, **kwargs):
    print(1000 * '*')
    ipn_obj = sender
    print(ipn_obj.receiver_email)
    order = Order.objects.get(id=28)
    order.email = ipn_obj.receiver_email
    order.save()
    if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
        pass

valid_ipn_received.connect(ipn_geter)
```

But after success paypal transaction `ipn_geter` does not execute. What should I do to fix it. Why i don't get ipn signals?

**EDITED:**

I read that I can't send ipn signal to `localhost` url, so I change it for testing using [ngrox](https://ngrok.com/). After running ngrox i send ipn signals end get 200 Status code for `paypal` url, but data dont changed and in console I don't see `*`, so functions does not executed. How I can fix this?